# Call a WebService Aysnchronously inside IHttpAsyncHandler

Tags: c#, web-services

I am trying to call a WebService inside my IHttpAsyncHandler and I see there is an answer like this
[Using an IHttpAsyncHandler to call a WebService Asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6388793/using-an-ihttpasynchandler-to-call-a-webservice-asynchronously/6389323#6389323)

I have questions about the answer. I appreciate if someone can help me.

It has

```
Task webClientDownloadTask = webClientDownloadCompletionSource.Task;
```

My questions are

1. webClientDownloadCompletionSource is not related to Webclient (client) object, so what is the point of doing this:

   // Get the TCS's task so that we can append some continuations
   Task webClientDownloadTask = webClientDownloadCompletionSource.Task;
2. What is "taskCompletionSource" in here:

   ```
       // Signal the TCS that were done (we don't actually look at the bool result, but it's needed)
       taskCompletionSource.SetResult(true);
   ```
3. Why I dispose() the WebClient in the ContinueWith() callback, why not just dispose() WEbClient after we set the taskCompletionSource.SetResult(true);?

   // Always dispose of the client once the work is completed
           webClientDownloadTask.ContinueWith(
               _ =>
               {
                   client.Dispose();
               },
               TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);

Here is the full code:

```
    public class MyAsyncHandler : IHttpAsyncHandler
{
    public IAsyncResult BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, object extraData)
    {
        // NOTE: the result of this operation is void, but TCS requires some data type so we just use bool
        TaskCompletionSource<bool> webClientDownloadCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

        WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
        HttpContext currentHttpContext = HttpContext.Current;

        // Setup the download completed event handler
        client.DownloadDataCompleted += (o, e) =>
        {
            if(e.Cancelled)
            {
                // If it was canceled, signal the TCS is cacnceled
                // NOTE: probably don't need this since you have nothing canceling the operation anyway
                webClientDownloadCompletionSource.SetCanceled();
            }
            else if(e.Error != null)
            {
                // If there was an exception, signal the TCS with the exception
                webClientDownloadCompletionSource.SetException(e.Error);
            }
            else
            {
                // Success, write the response
                currentHttpContext.Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
                currentHttpContext.Response.OutputStream.Write(e.Result, 0, e.Result.Length);

                // Signal the TCS that were done (we don't actually look at the bool result, but it's needed)
                taskCompletionSource.SetResult(true);
            }
        };

        string url = "url_web_service_url";

        // Kick off the download immediately
        client.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri(url));

        // Get the TCS's task so that we can append some continuations
        Task webClientDownloadTask = webClientDownloadCompletionSource.Task;

        // Always dispose of the client once the work is completed
        webClientDownloadTask.ContinueWith(
            _ =>
            {
                client.Dispose();
            },
            TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);

        // If there was a callback passed in, we need to invoke it after the download work has completed
        if(cb != null)
        {
            webClientDownloadTask.ContinueWith(
               webClientDownloadAntecedent =>
               {
                   cb(webClientDownloadAntecedent);
               },
               TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);
         }

        // Return the TCS's Task as the IAsyncResult
        return webClientDownloadTask;
    }

    public void EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        // Unwrap the task and wait on it which will propagate any exceptions that might have occurred
        ((Task)result).Wait();
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get 
        { 
            return true; // why not return true here? you have no state, it's easily reusable!
        }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this for an idea of what it's used for. There is also an example at the end

[TaskCompletionSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> In many scenarios, it is useful to enable a Task to represent
>   an external asynchronous operation. **TaskCompletionSource{TResult}** is
>   provided for this purpose. It enables the creation of a task that can
>   be handed out to consumers, and those consumers can use the members of
>   the task as they would any other. However, unlike most tasks, the
>   state of a task created by a TaskCompletionSource is controlled
>   explicitly by the methods on TaskCompletionSource. This enables the
>   completion of the external asynchronous operation to be propagated to
>   the underlying Task. The separation also ensures that consumers are
>   not able to transition the state without access to the corresponding
>   TaskCompletionSource.